# I think this reference request should not have been closed

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, vote-to-reopen

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/98899/haskell-code-accompanying-the-paul-hudak-1994-us-navy-experiment-paper

The paper cited is a much-referenced (in the PL world) classic. I can imagine finding the accompanying code would be an occasional if not frequent need to anyone who found the paper useful or interesting or even controversial.

I can think of no sane reason to close a useful question with a correct and useful answer. The only thing I can imagine is that since the mod didn't find the question interesting, they couldn't imagine that others might.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the time it took you to post this, I saw your flag on the question and reopened it. :)

That said, closing a question isn't always a bad thing. I am honestly on the fence on this one, cause on one hand it has been answered well, but on the other -- it is a very specific request. The odds of someone else having the same problem are relatively low, which makes the question a good candidate for "too localized".

Still, ultimately I think it can't hurt to leave it open in case someone else *does* read the same paper (I've no idea how popular it is) and goes looking for the sample code.

Comment: Thanks! I think Joel's comments about "too localized" here provide a fairly clear guideline: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1057/too-localized-by-population-size-instead-of-geographical-area